# How to Change Font Size and Formatting

Tags: azure-devops

Can someone let me know if it's possible to change the Font format in Azure DevOps description from with the dialog box itself?

It would appear that the description will retain the Font style from wherever it is copied from, and there is no way to change other than the default methods I have highlighted in RED in the screenshot

[image]

Is it possible to the change the Font Format other than to select the methods I have shown in RED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop the text into Word, format your changes, then copy-paste back into the Description.

Note: tables are a real PITA, but can be modified to some extent using Excel and finagling it until it works "good enough" for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to the change the Font Format other than to select the methods I have shown in RED?

It's not supported yet for `description` field in Work item.

Check the [Board roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline#updated-boards-experience), it only supports `Markdown editor for work item comments (preview)`, which you can edit the format like below, please note it's not released yet.

[image]

[image]

If you would like the markdown editor for description in work item, you can comment on the existing feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-markdown-as-an-alternative-to-ht/365464?q=Markdown%20Support).